# Eliminating text lines from a result of a JS pull

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a script that pulls an complete address block to be placed within a field of my choosing that works but now I am trying to eliminate unneeded parts of the resulting block of text for display.

The code:

```
<script>
 Sys.Application.add_load(
    function SetShipInfoValue()
    {
        var obj = document.getElementById("StepArea_UpdatePanelAddressBlock");

        if(obj == null)
        {
            var y = document.getElementsByClassName('ShippingAddressBlock');
            obj = y[0];
        }


        if(obj != null)
        {
            var txt = obj.innerHTML;
            var obj2 = document.getElementById("FIELD_1841");
            if(obj2 != null)
            {
                obj2.value = txt;
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

The result:

```
<div class="ShippingAddressBlock">
<div>Store 169</div> 
<div>General Manager</div> 
<div>1740 East Rd</div> 
<div></div> 
<div>Santa Clara, CA 92705</div> 
<div></div> 
<div></div>
<div>169</div>
</div>
```

How would I eliminate lines of text from the result to just display just the store number within the JS?

Comment: you just want to show 169?

Comment: Either of them.  Store 169 or the 169 at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting the last child from `.children`:

```js
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("ShippingAddressBlock")[0];
console.log(ele.children[ele.children.length-1].innerHTML); // 169
```

```html
<div class="ShippingAddressBlock">
<div>Store 169</div> 
<div>General Manager</div> 
<div>1740 East Rd</div> 
<div></div> 
<div>Santa Clara, CA 92705</div> 
<div></div> 
<div></div>
<div>169</div>
</div>
```

You can also use:

```
console.log(ele.lastChild.previousSibling.innerHTML);
```

Which will be supported in older browsers.

Comment: This seems correct but how would I go about injecting it into my output field? (Field_1841)

Comment: @HeathDoolin In the same way you did it in your question, just assign it to `.value` of your input element: `document.getElementById("FIELD_1841").value = ele.lastChild.previousSibling.innerHTML`.

Comment: "I am trying to eliminate unneeded parts of the resulting block of text for display" - This is not removing anything https://jsfiddle.net/em0z4p84/4/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith They want to display the result in their input element, this answer shows how to get the value they want. They just don't want to display the entire `div`. It's not wrong, did you look at what their current JS was doing? I even showed them how to set that item in a comment above, and mentioned how to assign it correct element.

Comment: I tried to replacing the document.get element with your suggestion and am not getting any result within the field.  Perhaps I am doing it wrong?  Sorry I am a bit of a novice here.

Comment: @HeathDoolin Are you sure the id is correct. [Here is a example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chkkocpa/), does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery filter like this https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/em0z4p84/2/

```
<div class="ShippingAddressBlock">
  <div>Store 169</div>
  <div>General Manager</div>
  <div>1740 East Rd</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>Santa Clara, CA 92705</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>169</div>
</div>

<script>
  $(".ShippingAddressBlock > div").filter(function(index) {
    if (index === 0) {
      $(this).attr('id', 'show');
    }
  });

</script>
```

CSS

```
.ShippingAddressBlock > div {
  display: none;
}

.ShippingAddressBlock > #show {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Note jQuery isn't in the tags of this question. I would recommend avoiding it unless the questioner mentions it or includes the tag.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Jquery is javascript. No?

Comment: Yes it is. But it's still a separate library. Would you use Angular.js in an answer to a question if the user isn't using it or mentioned it?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Depends on the question. At least my answer is given the desired effects, fix your answer.

Comment: How is my answer wrong? I think you should read the comments mentioned by the OP and their current JS code before down-voting other people.

Comment: The OP mentions *"to be placed within a field of my choosing"*, they don't want to edit the actual div element and remove all items other than the 169 `div`. They want to get the value and place it in a input field.